# ' __exidx_start' and '__exidx_end' what do they do?

Tags: linker-scripts

Hello I have a linker script in which i found this code  "`__exidx_start = .;`" which sets label value to the value of location counter "`.`". This label isn't used anywhere within the same linker script.

There is a similar label defined couple of lines below the first one and it is defined the same way "`__exidx_end = .;`".

These two labels are boundries of `.text` and `.rodata` sections, but i don't know **why would anyone define those two if they aren't used in the linker script?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These symbols are used internally by call-chain unwinding mechanism in GCC that takes control during exception handling phase. For instance, there is an example in  [unwind-arm-common.inc:104](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgcc/unwind-arm-common.inc#L104) where the boundaries of exception-handling table are obtained as pointers to these symbols.

As for `.ARM.exidx*`-entries that the symbols enclose, they form an exception-handling index table, which is a part of [ARM Exception Handling ABI (in sect. 4.4.1)](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0038b/IHI0038B_ehabi.pdf) for C++.

---

#### Update 20.05.2020

Answering the question by @pixelou:
These sections are not related to debugging, but form a basis of exception unwinding mechanism. Stripping the the `*.exidx*` sections causes disability to clean the mess up forcing program to `abort` (fail completly) instead of accurate handling of invalid states on stack. Without that unwinding information a program behaves like if it's built with [`-fno-exceptions` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_exceptions.html).

Comment: Does this section also relate to debugging? Is it necessary to have it in order to have a complete stack when debugging?

Comment: No, these entries are related only to the exception handling mechanism (roughly speaking they store the boundaries of try-except blocks and pointers to cleanup routines), and not to debugging. The information on function boundaries and line numbers is stored in `.debug_*` sections. (I've edited the answer, tried to clarify it considering your question.)

Answer (score 2):

They're not used in the linker script, but they are declared as extern variables and used in the gcc library. Take them out, and this is what happens:

```
.../gcc/config/arm/unwind-arm.c:614: undefined reference to `__exidx_start'
.../gcc/config/arm/unwind-arm.c:614: undefined reference to `__exidx_end'
```

Comment: But.. What do they do?